# How to fix ' Not all arguments converted during string formatting? '

Tags: python-3.7

I am learning python. while doing an exercise, i encountered a problem

> Python TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I tried to refer and change the code but nothing worked well.

```
my_list=input(list)
for num in my_list:
    if(num%2==0):
        print(f"{num} is even number")
    else:
        print(f'{num} is odd number')
```

I expected the output should be either `num is even number` or `num is odd number` for every number in the list. Unfortunately I get the error message above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you giving the input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list=map(int, input().split())
for num in my_list:
    if(num%2==0):
        print(f"{num} is even number")
    else:
        print(f'{num} is odd number')
```

give the input space seperated integers for eg : "1 2 3 4" without quotes. The output should be as expected. 
The error is probably due to the input format which you might be giving in list for mat i.e "[1,2,3,4]" which not implicitly decoded by string formatting in python. To input list of numbers you might want to use the way i have mentioned in the code.